# Fallo al intentar pasar un array desde PHP a JS

Tags: javascript, php, json

Tengo un archivo PHP donde he generado un array y dentro de un select quiero que cuando se haga una selección nueva se ejecute una función Javascript que tengo definida en otro fichero.

En el PHP tengo:

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria" value="" class="mauticform-input" type="text"  data-lengthMin="1" onchange='configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById("subcategoria"),<?php echo json_encode ($array_final); ?>)'>
```

Mi duda principal es cómo le paso el JSON entrecomillado porque estoy viendo que ni con escapes ni dobles o comillas simples llega bien al otro lado. Seguro que no estoy viendo alguna tontería.

Y en el JS lo recibo (sin el array funciona bien y se conectan):

```
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1, ddl2, array) {

    var arrayJS = JSON.parse(array);

    createOption(ddl2, ddl1.value, ddl1.value);
    var casa = ['Black', 'White', 'Blue'];
  
    switch (ddl1.value) {
      case '1':
        ddl2.options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < casa.length; i++) {
          createOption(ddl2, casa[i], casa[i]);
        }
        break;
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: Vigila, porque si el array de PHP es key => value el json_encode te genera un objeto, pero si el array es autonumérico te generará un array de JS.
Quizás tus problemas van por ahí... $array['1'] = 1 VS $array[] = 1;

Comment: Pero a ver, ¿qué se supone que intentas hacer con todo esto: `onchange='configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById("subcategoria"),<?php echo json_encode ($array_final); ?>)'>`? NO mezcles contextos (código Javascript con código PHP en un mismo contexto), es una pésima práctica. Y no pongas funciones in-line en los elementos HTML como `onchange` y otras, es OTRA pésima práctica. En Javascript alcanza el elemento por su ID y usa eventos de escucha y para comunicar entre cliente y servidor usa Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.

Comment: @Pepote Muchas gracias por la apreciación, me dio la pista para solucionar.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por la corrección y las indicaciones para desarrollar con mejores prácticas.

Comment: @PedroRR Si lo has solucionado agrega la respuesta que te ha funcionado para que la comunidad lo sepa, gracias.